# ksoap2 custom serialized response

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm having problems with casting response to my custom class:
Here is the code which calls request:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(RequestData.NAMESPACE, METHOD_LOGIN);
request.addProperty(PROPERTY_USERNAME, RequestData.USERNAME);
request.addProperty(PROPERTY_API_KEY, RequestData.API_KEY);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = false;
envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(RequestData.URL);
transport.debug = true;
transport.call("", envelope);
LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse)envelope.bodyIn;
```

And here is serialized response class:

```
public class LoginResponse implements KvmSerializable {
String sessionId;

public LoginResponse(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
}

public LoginResponse() {
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int i) {
    return sessionId;

}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int i, Object o) {
    sessionId = o.toString();

}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    propertyInfo.name = "loginReturn";

}
}
```

Error I get says: SoapObject cannot be cast to com.myapp...LoginResponse. It happens at this line:

```
    LoginResponse response = (LoginResponse)envelope.bodyIn;
```

If I write

```
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse;
```

instead of previous line, I don't get error, but I want to do it with custom serialized class.
Also, how to handle failed response?
Thanks